# Icon and Text in Button not aligned vertically

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add an `Icon` and some text in a `Button` (also tried `Chip` and `Badge` from `react-native-paper`). For some reason the `Icon` is always a little above the text.

With `View` it works perfectly, but once I introduce `Button`, `Chip` or `Badge`, the items missalign.

```
// Working with View
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
   <MaterialIcon name='access-time' size={iconSize2} color={themeColors[2]} />
   <Text variant="titleLarge" style={{ color: themeColors[2], fontFamily: defaultFont }}>&nbsp;12:00 - 21:30</Text>
</View>

// Missaligned with Button
<Button style={{ backgroundColor: themeColors[2], flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <MaterialIcon name='access-time' size={iconSize2} color={'whitesmoke'} />
  <Text variant="titleLarge" style={{ color: themeColors[2], fontFamily: defaultFont }}>&nbsp;12:00 - 21:30</Text>
</Button>
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Can somebody tell me if I'm doing something incorrect?

Things tried:

1. Add `paddingTop` to `Button`
2. Add `marginTop` to `Icon`
3. Change `height` of `Button` and/or `Icon`

Comment: Is the button ```display: flex```?

Comment: @Akusas I think it is. For testing I set it to `display: flex`, did not change the layout unfortunatly.

Comment: @zhrchi I haven't worked with react-native-paper, but looking into docs. Have you tried using this component: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/SegmentedButtons/

Comment: @Akusas I just tried it. `icon: <MaterialIcon name='access-time' size={iconSize2} color={themeColors[2]} />` and `icon: 'access-time'` both don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```html
<Button style={{ backgroundColor: themeColors[2], flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', padding: 0, borderWidth: 0 }}>
  <MaterialIcon name='access-time' size={iconSize2} color={'whitesmoke'} />
  <Text style={{ color: themeColors[2], fontFamily: defaultFont }}>&nbsp;12:00 - 21:30</Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tried it, no difference compared to the image.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation all the way at the bottom of the webpage there is a sample for `Icon`'s with `Button`'s.

Example that worked for me as well:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const myButton = (
  <Icon.Button
    name="facebook"
    backgroundColor="#3b5998"
    onPress={this.loginWithFacebook}
  >
    Login with Facebook
  </Icon.Button>
);

const customTextButton = (
  <Icon.Button name="facebook" backgroundColor="#3b5998">
    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 15 }}>
      Login with Facebook
    </Text>
  </Icon.Button>
);
```